# Create React App doesn't load on ios device

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a ReactJS PWA. When I load the URL from my desktop and android, it works totally fine. But when I use iPhone, it shows a blank with a background image that I set to body tag. But it's blank.

By the way, I've used `npx create-react-app` for my project.

Can you please tell me why this is happening and what's the solution?

Comment: We need more information. Did you change anything after you ran `npx create-react-app`?

Comment: maybe you're running into CORS error if you are doing rest api calls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864017/ionic-ios-issue-white-page-when-doing-rest-calls

Comment: @torvin No I developed the whole app. It's in the final stage.

Comment: @Ani previously I disabled firebase and then it loaded on ios.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is lack of information and I cannot help you.